# Print environment variables and functions as executable commands in bash

Tags: bash

In bash, if you run `alias` in the terminal, it prints out a list of the defined aliases as commands, like this:

```
alias foo=bar
```

If you wanted to, you could `alias > my_aliases.sh` and  then `source my_aliases.sh`. I want the same thing but for environment variables and defined functions.

`env` seemed like it might work but this doesn't quite work. I need this to output environment variables and functions but I'm seeing lines like this in the output of `env`:

```
BASH_FUNC_foo()=() {  ls foo 
}
```

`foo` is the actual name of my function but I can't add the output of `env` into a file and `source` it. If I did, the script would error like this:

```
bash: test.sh: line 8: `BASH_FUNC_pkgs()=() {  pkg ls "$@"'
```

Is there maybe a way to print just the environment variables and then print the exported functions in some other way that is execute-friendly? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `declare -p` will print all variables in a reuseable format, including export/integer/readonly/etc. attributes.

  ```
  declare -x USER="jkugelman"
  declare -x USERNAME="jkugelman"
  declare -x VISUAL="vim"
  ```
- `declare -fp` will print all functions in a reuseable format.

  ```
  reload () 
  { 
      history -a;
      exec bash -l
  }
  ```
- If you don't care about attributes a bare `declare` will print both variables and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `set` command with no arguments

```
set > variables_and_functions.bash
```

Ref [4.3.1 The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)

Comment: Note, this is worse than John's answer, in that the scope of the variables is not "declared".